# Polygon labels with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geojson

Using leaflet 7.3 and polygon data in GeoJSON, how can I add labels from field: NAME?

Here is example of current GeoJSON polygon data. I would like to enable fixed labels in center of polygon, overlap OK.

```
var districts = L.geoJson(null, {
  style: function (feature) {
    return {
      color: "green",
      fill: true,
      opacity: 0.8
    };
  },


onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('mouseover', function () {
      this.setStyle({
        'fillColor': '#0000ff'
      });
    });
    layer.on('mouseout', function () {
      this.setStyle({
        'fillColor': '#ff0000'
      });
    });
    layer.on('click', function () {
    window.location = feature.properties.URL;
    });
}

});

$.getJSON("data/districts.geojson", function (data) {
  districts.addData(data);
});
```

Comment: I think you forgot to define onEachFeature callback in L.geoJson options. See http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson

Answer (score 5):

In **onEachFeature** callback, you can get the center of the L.Polygon created by GeoJSON layer and bind a label to it.

```
var polygonCenter = layer.getBounds().getCenter();

// e.g. using Leaflet.label plugin
L.marker(polygonCenter)
    .bindLabel(feature.properties['NAME'], { noHide: true })
    .addTo(map);
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/ro54bqbz/ using [Leaflet.label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label)

Comment: Do I add this to already called oneachfeature, or create a new one? So far I am getting an error: "TypeError: e is undefined"

Comment: did you include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label/master/dist/leaflet.label.js and https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label/blob/master/dist/leaflet.label.css ?

Comment: there is a mistake in app1o8bd13e.js ... onEachFeature: function (feature, layer). At the moment, you have onEachFeature(feature, layer). You can use your browser javascript console to see this error

Comment: I've updated code but I get the "bindLabel is not a function" error.